# Group the contents of a Map of LocalDates into a Map of Ranges of dates

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, collectors, localdate

I have a map of working shifts indexed by day `Map<LocalDate, Collection<Shift>> shiftsAllDays`
such as:

```
"2020-03-26": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "startTime": "21:00:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "startTime": "09:00:00",
    }
  ],
  "2020-03-27": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "startTime": "22:00:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "startTime": "10:00:00",
    }
  ],
  ...
]
```

as it can be seen, the shifts have an id and a start hour.

But to have the map indexed by day is a waste: the shifts happen to be consistently the same, except for one thing. The start hour is `LocalTime`, so the only difference in the shifts, is that after applying the timezone, the resulting shifts only differ in hour when a DST flip takes place.

I want to do some sort of `groupBy` in the collector, to have something of the like:

```
Range.of(2020-01-01 ... 2020-03-26) [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "startTime": "21:00:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "startTime": "09:00:00",
    }
],
Range.of(2020-03-27 ... 2020-10-30) [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "startTime": "22:00:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "startTime": "10:00:00",
    }
],
Range.of(2020-10-31 ... 2021-01-01) [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "startTime": "21:00:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "startTime": "09:00:00",
    }
]
```

...grouped in `Ranges` from DST flip to DST flip. I'm having a hard time writing a `Collectors.groupBy(...)` and transforming the key from a single `LocalDate` day, to a `Range<LocalDate>`

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you would include a [mre]  that shows existing code including class definition and the actual source for the map initialization. (rather than a text representation of the map).

Comment: that's difficult since I'm getting this data structure coming from a external query to elsewhere. The relevant part here is that the Shift entity has an identifier and a LocalTime

Comment: You know the class definition.  You know what the map looks like.   Just come up with some data and show a populated map with the included class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution with custom Range class

To begin with, you need to define a class `Range` with two fields (*start date* and *end date*), and create a list of ranges. Since only three instance are required, it makes sense to declare this list as a `public static final` field within a utility class.

Below is an example of `Range`, for the purpose of conciseness I've implemented it as Java 16 record. It is given one utility method which is meant to check whether the given date is within this instance of *range*:

```
public record Range(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
    public boolean isWithinRange(LocalDate date) { // start inclusive, end exclusive
        return date.isBefore(start) || date.isBefore(end) && date.isAfter(start);
    }
}
```

A list of ranges:

```
public static final List<Range> RANGES =
    List.of(new Range(LocalDate.of(2020,1, 1), LocalDate.of(2020,3, 27)),
            new Range(LocalDate.of(2020,3, 27), LocalDate.of(2020,10, 31)),
            new Range(LocalDate.of(2020,10, 31), LocalDate.of(2021,1, 1)));
```

Utility method `getRange()` that is responsible for retrieving an instance of `Range` from the list of ranges based on the given date:

```
public static Range getRange(LocalDate data) {
    return RANGES.stream()
        .filter(range -> range.isWithinRange(data))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow();
}
```

Dummy record `Shift` (*used for testing purposes*):

```
public record Shift(int id, LocalTime startTime) {}
```

In order to approach the conversion of a `Map<LocalDate, Collection<Shift>>` into a `Map<Range, List<Shift>>` with streams, we need to create a stream of map entries. Than make use of collector `groupingBy()` in order to group the data by *range*. As the downstream collector of `groupingBy()` we have to provide `flatMapping()` in order to flatten the data associated with a particular data (so that all `Shift` objects that will be mapped to the same *range* would be placed in the same collection). And a downstream of `flatMapping()` we need to provide a collector which defines how store (*or how to perform reduction*) flattened elements. In the data *collector* `toList()` is used to store the data mapped to the same key in a list.

`main()` - demo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<LocalDate, Collection<Shift>> shiftsByDate =
        Map.of(LocalDate.of(2020,3, 26),
                   List.of(new Shift(4, LocalTime.of(21, 0, 0)), new Shift(5, LocalTime.of(9, 0, 0))),
               LocalDate.of(2020,3, 27),
                   List.of(new Shift(4, LocalTime.of(22, 0, 0)), new Shift(5, LocalTime.of(10, 0, 0)))
            );
    
    Map<Range, List<Shift>> shiftsByRange = shiftsByDate.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(entry -> getRange(entry.getKey()),
            Collectors.flatMapping(entry -> entry.getValue().stream(),
                Collectors.toList())));
    
    shiftsByRange.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " : " + v));
}
```

*Output*

```
Range[start=2020-10-31, end=2021-01-01] : [Shift[id=4, startTime=22:00], Shift[id=5, startTime=10:00]]
Range[start=2020-01-01, end=2020-03-27] : [Shift[id=4, startTime=21:00], Shift[id=5, startTime=09:00]]
```

#### Solution with Range from the Spring Data

The previous version required moderate only changes in order to use `Range<T>` from the Spring Data project. We need to fix the list `RANGES` where these objects are instantiated, and replace the type `Range` with the `Range<T>`.

*There's caveat:* if you expect generic type parameter `<T>` to be `LocalDate` - it's not correct and wouldn't work.

`Range<T>` class expects its generic type to be comparable, i.e. `T extends Comparable<T>` and `LocalDate` doesn't extend comparable directly, it implements `ChronoLocalDate` interface which in turn implements `Comparable` interface and `LocalDate` inherits its default implementation of `compareTo()`.

*In other words:*

- it's **incorrect** to say that `LocalDate` *extends* `Comparable<LocalDate>`
- because in fact `LocalDate` *extends* `Comparable<ChronoLocalDate>`.

Therefore, we have to use `ChronoLocalDate` as a generic type.

The `RANGES` list will look like that:

```
public static final List<Range<ChronoLocalDate>> RANGES =
    List.of(Range.rightOpen(LocalDate.of(2020,1, 1), LocalDate.of(2020,3, 27)),
            Range.rightOpen(LocalDate.of(2020,3, 27), LocalDate.of(2020,10, 31)),
            Range.rightOpen(LocalDate.of(2020,10, 31), LocalDate.of(2021,1, 1)));
```

Method `getRange()` which is responsible for retrieving an instance of `Range` from the list of ranges based on the given date:

```
public static Range<ChronoLocalDate> getRange(LocalDate data) {
    return RANGES.stream()
        .filter(range -> range.contains(data))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow();
}
```

`main()` - demo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<LocalDate, Collection<Shift>> shiftsByDate =
        Map.of(LocalDate.of(2020,3, 26),
                   List.of(new Shift(4, LocalTime.of(21, 0, 0)), new Shift(5, LocalTime.of(9, 0, 0))),
               LocalDate.of(2020,3, 27),
                   List.of(new Shift(4, LocalTime.of(22, 0, 0)), new Shift(5, LocalTime.of(10, 0, 0)))
        );
    
    Map<Range<ChronoLocalDate>, List<Shift>> shiftsByRange = shiftsByDate.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(entry -> getRange(entry.getKey()),
            Collectors.flatMapping(entry -> entry.getValue().stream(),
                Collectors.toList())));
    
    shiftsByRange.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " : " + v));
}
```

*Output:*

```
[2020-03-27-2020-10-31) : [Shift[id=4, startTime=22:00], Shift[id=5, startTime=10:00]]
[2020-01-01-2020-03-27) : [Shift[id=4, startTime=21:00], Shift[id=5, startTime=09:00]]
```

Comment: I feel like I'm missing what `getRange()` is doing. It is critical that, I can't provide an static list of ranges. The boundaries of the different ranges have to be dynamically computed everytime there a DST flip.
Also, is there a reason why I can work with the Java built-in Range class?

Comment: @diegoruizbarbero Accidentally missed the `getRange()`, sorry. Updated the answer.

Comment: @diegoruizbarbero There's no `Range` class in `java.time` package as far as I know. Can provide a link to the documentation of the class to which you refer?

Comment: My bad, there is one packed within Spring framework: `org.springframework.data.domain.Range<T>`

Comment: @diegoruizbarbero I got it working with the `Range<T>` from the Spring Data and updated the answer. It would be better if you would specify this information in the question.

Comment: Your answer is helpful. However, the period of dates, is a-priori, unknown -so I don't have any means to build myself the RANGES. I'm trying to do this in two steps: first build the RANGES, using a reduce() that spots when DST flips take place ...and later applying your approach